# Get min, max, and total length of wav files

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, wav, sox

I have a folder with several hundred `wav` files. I want to get the minimum length, in milliseconds, of the shortest wav file and the maximum length, respectively. I also want to get the total length of all files.

I know I can use `sox` and `sed` to get the length of a single wav file, like this

```
sox some_file.wav -n stat 2>&1 | sed -n 's#^Length (seconds):[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\)$#\1#p'
```

The easiest way I can think of is to use a `Python` script that loops trough all my files, since they all have generic, consecutive file names ({001-800}.wav), and call the above code. However, I'm not sure how to do that. I know `subprocess` should be the module to use, but I couldn't figure out how to pipe.

Currently I'm stuck with something along this line:

```
import subprocess
import shlex

min = 1000
max = 0
total = 0

for i in range(1,801):
    cmd = "sox %03d.wav -n stat 2>&1 | sed -n 's#^Length (seconds):[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\)$#\1#p" % i
    subprocess.call(shlex.split(cmd))

    # here is where I would catch the output and do the calculations with min, max, and total
```

Comment: related: [Retrieving the output of subprocess.call()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1996518/4279)

Comment: If you're under linux (if you use sox commands, I think it's the case), you could simply use a shell script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cmd` in your example is a shell pipeline. `subprocess.call()` doesn't call the shell by default i.e., your command should fail unless you specify `shell=True` (use string argument in this case). To get output, you could call:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
```

You could avoid calling shell commands and use pure Python parser demonstrated in [How to get .avi files length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17185348/4279) question instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from glob import glob
from hachoir_metadata import extractMetadata
from hachoir_parser import createParser

entries = [(path, extractMetadata(createParser(path)).get('duration'))
           for path in glob(u"*.wav")]
print "Min: path(%s), duration(%s)" % min(entries, key=lambda (_,d): d)
print "Max: path(%s), duration(%s)" % max(entries, key=lambda (_,d): d)
print "Total: duration(%s seconds)" % sum(d.total_seconds() for _, d in entries)
```

To install [the hachoir library](https://bitbucket.org/haypo/hachoir/wiki/hachoir-metadata), run:

```
$ pip install hachoir-{core,parser,metadata}
```