# reading and parsing Windows video files metadata in Python

Tags: python, windows, metadata

I'm working on a project and I need to read and parse video metadata.(duration, date created,title,bit rate , ...)
as far as I know there isn't any good package for Python 3.X for this issue.

**1** -- I found these :

[enzyme](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enzyme/)

[hachoir-metadata](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hachoir-metadata/1.3.3)

but they are designed for python 2.X

**2** -- 
I also know [how to use ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31025482/5284370) and other libraries that process video files. but they are so slow, I want to simply read the metadata from the windows file.

**3** -- I tried to use [exifread](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ExifRead) package to read video metadata , but as far as I found out , it doesn't work on video files.

**4** -- there was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38596983/5284370) question that asked for a way to retrieve *only* length of videos, but it is unanswered.

**I'm looking for this**:

```
file = open(path_to_video_file)
props = python_video_info_parser.get_info(file)
print(props)
```

**platform**:

python 3.4
windows 10

Comment: You can use the cli version of mediainfo and print all the metadata.
https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download/Windows

Answer (score 0):

I hope you found what you are looking for. :)

But if you did not or others are wondering.. I am researching the same sunject and I may have found a solution.

What I have found so far is a command-line tool called exiftool.
If you download this software and use the command line feature you are able to run these commands with the subprocess module.

There is support for a lot of file formats, as shown in the documentation.

I will update this post as soon as I have found a working soltuion. :)

You can download the tool [here](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).